# Why do I get an exception when querying odata service for values that contain null?

Tags: oracle, wcf-data-services, odata

I have an OData service running on top of Oracle database. I can query it like this:

```
http://localhost:4930/Oracle.svc/XXKE_L2E_ADDRESSES_V%28%29?
$filter=PARTY_ID eq 10925&$select=*
```

and then everything works fine.

For the following also everything works fine (none of the fields contains null value):

```
http://localhost:4930/Oracle.svc/XXKE_L2E_ADDRESSES_V%28%29?
$filter=PARTY_ID eq 10925&
$select=ADDRESS_ID,PARTY_ID,CITY,ADDRESS1,PARTY_NAME
```

But the following fails (ADDRESS2 is a field that contains null):

```
http://localhost:4930/Oracle.svc/XXKE_L2E_ADDRESSES_V%28%29?
$filter=PARTY_ID eq 10925&
$select=ADDRESS_ID,PARTY_ID,CITY,ADDRESS1,PARTY_NAME,ADDRESS2
```

The response I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="pl-PL">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
  <innererror>
    <message>Value cannot be null.&#xD;
Parameter name: value</message>
    <type>System.ArgumentNullException</type>
    <stacktrace>   at System.Data.Services.WebUtil.CheckArgumentNull[T](T value, String parameterName)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.Internal.ProjectedWrapper.set_PropertyNameList(String value)&#xD;
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )&#xD;
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.Internal.ProjectedWrapper.EnumeratorWrapper.MoveNext()&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()</stacktrace>
  </innererror>
</error>
```

Why do I get an error? What's the problem with a null? I get it without problems when i specify `$select=*`. How to overcome this problem?

**EDIT:**

I figured out that I am facing exactly the same problem as described here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2362250. I removed the fields, so there are only 8 and then I can select all of them. If I have 9 fields I can only select 6 of them at a time. If I have 10 fields I can only select 3 of them at a time.

If someone has a solution, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message from Oracle guy:

"MS has identified a couple of potential fixes they could make to resolve this issue. Oracle has provided its feedback. We're waiting to hear whether MS agrees and which release or patch they plan on including the fix with."

So there is no solution for it yet, but the workaround that I use is just selecting all the fields ('*') and then picking the ones that I am interested in from code. At least it works :)

Comment: "MS has told us they believe they have fixed the issue in WCF Data Services Client 5.1. The fix should be in the 5.1.0-rc version on NuGet. http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client/5.0.2 "